# Oxidation of ethanol to acetaldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

In my book, it is written the best method to oxidise ethanol into acetaldehyde is a three step process:

$\ce{(i) TsCl (ii) DMSO (iii) NaHCO3}$

Why is this better than other methods, such as the following:

$\ce{(A) H+/KMnO4, heat}$

$\ce{(B) H+/K2Cr2O7, heat}$

$\ce{(C) MnO2, heat}$

Comment: Well, actually getting ethanal looks like major plus here.

Comment: @Mithoron then in others what are other products

Comment: Why it has got too many down votes

Comment: Because you didn't say anything about your knowledge, simply putting random oxidants of alcohols is, welll...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because none of the other methods quoted will work. Permanganate and Dichromate will overoxidise and give acetic acid. Manganese dioxide won't touch it.

Comment: why MnO2 will not touch it ?

Comment: MnO2 only oxidises benzylic and sometimes allylic alcohols.

Comment: I stand corrected. Manganese dioxide WILL oxidise alcohols to aldehydes under solvent free conditions. Haven't actually used it myself for thus. Tet. Letts 43 2002 6149

Comment: I heard that dichromate could work too in controlled situation.

Comment: Dichromate plus pyridine so that you have in-situ PDC should be OK but that's not what the OP specified